# Garbled text in string - numbers appearing

Tags: javascript

Does anybody know a way to take this garbled text and remove all of the numbers in the code bellow? The idea is to take in a string and clean out all numeric characters, and return a string with spacing and special characters ~#$%^&!@*():;"'.,? all intact. is there a way?

```
stringClean('! !') == '! !'
stringClean('123456789') == ''
stringClean('This looks5 grea8t!') == 'This looks great!'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression to match `\d+` (digit characters), and replace all occurrences with the empty string:

```js
const stringClean = str => str.replace(/\d+/g, '');
console.log(
  stringClean('! !') == '! !',
  stringClean('123456789') == '',
  stringClean('This looks5 grea8t!') == 'This looks great!'
);
```